# How to serve the same page for all URLs?

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7 as an API to send JSON data to a Backbone application. It is a single page site with its HTML markup in `html.tpl.php`.

Everything works fine with the Backbone router when I start on the homepage and navigate with internal links but when I refresh a page or type a URL directly I get a Drupal 404 error.

How can I make unknown pages to serve the same page all the time?

The `.htaccess` redirects to `index.php` so it's not a browser 404 but a Drupal 404.

Comment: Just add a redirect rule forwarding all traffic that isn't the homepage to the homepage

Comment: @Clive Isn't it what Drupal's default `.htaccess` do? The URL must be preserved as the Backbone router uses `pushState` to handle navigation.

Comment: No it _rewrites_ requests for non existent files/folders to index.php. A _redirect_ is different. You should base it on the request uri, as in "if the URL isn't '/', isn't an existing file or folder, redirect to '/',but with whatever extra rules you need (/user and /admin spring to mind)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is stick your webapp in a folder on the root of the site (i.e. `/app`). Then tell `.htaccess` to route all traffic under `/app` to `/app/index.html`. This way, everything `/app` routes to your SPA while everything else is handled by Drupal and you don't mess with Drupal's routing.

Besides, you *really* don't want to route *all* 404 pages to your SPA. For instance, if you delete a piece of content in the site or uninstall a module (that removes its config sections), you will want a Drupal 404 to happen, not your SPA.

Comment: That would work but the Drupal administration navbar wouldn't, right? And I would have to add an exception for `/user` in order to log into the administration panel. If there is no alternative I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same issue, it only happens when connected to Drupal's admin panel. I solved it by disconnecting…